# @font-face problems with importing some font

Tags: css, fonts, typography

I'm making some site and I want to import font. I put it into folder fonts.

```
@font-face{
font-family: Alex;
src:local("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}

h1{
font-family: Alex, "Helvetica Neue", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 70px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;

}
```

How to make this works?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to change is only a small thing:

Change this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Alex;
    src:local("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Into:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Alex;
    src:url("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
    /* Changed src:local to src:url */
}
```

Hope this helps!